# Css columns strange height

Tags: css

I have columns and need have 15 padding at top and bottom of background

https://jsfiddle.net/d5hd6zae/

```css
.b-cat_outer {
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.b-cat{
 padding:15px 15px 0px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 -webkit-columns: 4;
 -moz-columns: 4;
 columns: 4;
 -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
 -moz-column-gap: 10px;
 column-gap: 10px;
}
.b-cat__item{
    position: relative;
 color:#000;
 font-size:13px;
 padding:0;
 margin:0 0 10px;
 line-height:1.4;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 white-space:nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }

.b-cat__item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
   
.b-cat__link{
    color: #026dc0;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
  float:left;
 }
.b-cat__link:hover{
 color:#8c0400;
   }
```

```html
<div class="b-cat_outer">    
    <div class="b-cat">
        <div class="b-cat__item">
            <a class="b-cat__link" href="#">Fisrt</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b-cat__item">
            <a class="b-cat__link" href="#">Second</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b-cat__item">
            <a class="b-cat__link" href="#">Third</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b-cat__item">
            <a class="b-cat__link" href="#">Other</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b-cat__item">
            <a class="b-cat__link" href="#">Another</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b-cat__item">
            <a class="b-cat__link" href="#">Once more</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b-cat__item">
            <a class="b-cat__link" href="#">Third</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b-cat__item">
            <a class="b-cat__link" href="#">Other</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b-cat__item">
            <a class="b-cat__link" href="#">Another</a>
        </div>
        <div class="b-cat__item">
            <a class="b-cat__link" href="#">Once more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Element height is 18px.
Emement bottom margin is 10px.
Last element bottom margin is 0.

But outer block height is 55px (When two rows). Why? I expect it should be 46.

Comment: if you want a padding at bottom and top padding:15px 15px 0px; is wrong. It should be padding:15px 0; or padding:15px 0 15px 0;

Comment: It won't solve the problem. Now  `.b-cat` has padding top, left and right 15px and margin bottom 15px. The problem is with its inner height

Comment: did you mean `css` in your title??